# Jquery Parent Item of Div containing X content

Tags: jquery

I need to add a CSS class to the TR (or multiple TR's) of the parent of a TD containing some specific text.

Because of the CMS I can't control the code, but I can add some Jquery and CSS.

I've tried a few things, but I've had no luck.

Here is an example of what I had in mind.

```
<style>
  tr.highlight { background: Blue;}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Pet
    </td>
    <td>
     Number of Legs
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cat
    </td>
    <td>
      4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Doggie
    </td>
    <td>
      4
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I essentially want the jquery to add that class (highlight) to the offending TR.

** I know this is not an ideal approach, but desperate times call for desperate measures. **

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is it in the example that you want to highlight?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to highlight the TR containing Doggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for [the `:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

The following will add the class `highlight` to the parent element (should be `TR`) of every TD containing the string `"doggie"`:

```
$('td:contains("doggie")').parent().addClass('highlight');
```

Note that the text must have matching case to be selected, i.e. `$('td:contains("doggie")` and `$('td:contains("DoGGiE")')`aren’t the same!